# Get latest entry per group in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

As per Gunwant's request, I wanted to provide more information about my problem.

I have a database with >10^7 rows. Each row is a product with many different attributes (columns), e.g. title, description, price, weight, color, volume, warehouse_location and many more. However, all of these attributes are subject to change - the price might go up or down, the description might change, it might be moved to another location in the warehouse, etc. All data is stored historically, e.g.:

```
description |       date | price | warehouse_location |  color
   Cucumber | 2017-01-14 |    50 |                23A |  green
   Cucumber | 2017-01-16 |    55 |                23A |  green
   Cucumber | 2017-01-19 |    52 |                14B |  green
  Pineapple | 2017-01-12 |    80 |                23A | yellow
  Pineapple | 2017-01-17 |    75 |                23A | yellow
  Pineapple | 2017-01-22 |    80 |                23A | yellow
      Lemon | 2017-01-18 |    60 |                 9C | yellow
      Lemon | 2017-01-19 |    70 |                33E | yellow
      Lemon | 2017-01-20 |    80 |                 9A | yellow
```

I now want to create arbitrary reports, I need to be able to filter every column.

For example: Price of all objects with warehouse_location 23A from 2017-01-12 to 2017-01-18. If the same object has multiple matches for a given query, only the most recent entry within that timespan should be returned. In this case, "55" should be returned for "Cucumber" and "75" for pineapple.

I need to be able to filter multiple columns at once. Another example would be "Color of all objects with price > 60 and price < 90 and date > 2017-01-11 and date < 2017-01-22" which should return { yellow; yellow } for the above dataset.

Original question:

I want to store historical data in a Cassandra database:

```
objectid |       date | price | foo
       1 | 2017-01-18 |   200 |   A
       1 | 2017-01-19 |   300 |   A
       1 | 2017-01-20 |   400 |   B
       2 | 2017-01-18 |   100 |   C
       2 | 2017-01-19 |   150 |   C
       2 | 2017-01-20 |   200 |   D
       3 | 2017-01-18 |   400 |   E
       3 | 2017-01-19 |   350 |   E
       3 | 2017-01-20 |   300 |   F
```

I now want to select the latest entry for the "foo" column of each object that satisfies a condition. For example, for the query price between 300 and 500 I want to get the following:

```
objectid |       date | price | foo
       1 | 2017-01-20 |   400 |   B
       3 | 2017-01-18 |   400 |   E
```

Are queries like these possible in Cassandra?

Edit:
Thanks everyone for your effort. Marko Švaljek's answer seems to work if you only want to get unique values of foo. In my use case, I have dozens of different "foo columns" and >10^7 rows. I apparantly would have to create hundreds of different "report" tables to allow arbitrary filtering - I'm not sure if Cassandra is the right solution for that use case.

Comment: You need to specify your requirement. Be specific, provide all the information, there is nothing impossible with cassandra.

Comment: I updated my question with more details - is the problem now clearer?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always with cassandra you would need to denormalize this. I will assume
your base table is something like following:

```
create table base (
    objectid int,
    date timestamp,
    price int,
    foo text,
    primary key (objectid, date)
);
```

please be very careful with this create statements because
historical data usually grows way above 100 000'ts

Then I created following insert statements:

```
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (1, '2017-01-18', 200, 'A');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (1, '2017-01-19', 300, 'A');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (1, '2017-01-20', 400, 'B');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (2, '2017-01-18', 100, 'C');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (2, '2017-01-19', 150, 'C');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (2, '2017-01-20', 200, 'D');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (3, '2017-01-18', 400, 'E');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (3, '2017-01-19', 350, 'E');
 insert into base (objectid, date, price, foo) values (3, '2017-01-20', 300, 'F');
```

It's not possible to get the query you want out of the box. But you can go
around it.

You need to create another table:

```
create table report (
    report text,
    price int,
    objectid int,
    date timestamp,
    foo text,
    primary key (report, price, foo)
);

-- in cassandra if you want to search for something it has to go into clustering columns
-- and price is your first goal ... foo is there just for uniqueness 
-- now you do inserts with data that you have above
-- perfectly o.k. to create multiple inserts in cassandra 
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-18', 200, 'A');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-19', 300, 'A');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-20', 400, 'B');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-18', 100, 'C');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-19', 150, 'C');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-20', 200, 'D');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-18', 400, 'E');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-19', 350, 'E');
insert into report (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-20', 300, 'F');
```

This would return you:

```
select objectid, date, price, foo from report where report='latest' and price > 300 and price < 500;

 objectid | date                            | price | foo
----------+---------------------------------+-------+-----
        3 | 2017-01-18 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   350 |   E
        1 | 2017-01-19 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   400 |   B
        3 | 2017-01-17 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   400 |   E
```

And this is not what you want. You have couple of options now.

Basically if you exclude price from primary key you will get:

```
create table report2 (
    report text,
    price int,
    objectid int,
    date timestamp,
    foo text,
    primary key (report, foo)
 );

insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-18', 200, 'A');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-19', 300, 'A');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 1, '2017-01-20', 400, 'B');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-18', 100, 'C');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-19', 150, 'C');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 2, '2017-01-20', 200, 'D');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-18', 400, 'E');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-19', 350, 'E');
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('latest', 3, '2017-01-20', 300, 'F');

select objectid, date, price, foo from report2 where report='latest';

 objectid | date                            | price | foo
----------+---------------------------------+-------+-----
        1 | 2017-01-18 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   300 |   A
        1 | 2017-01-19 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   400 |   B
        2 | 2017-01-18 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   150 |   C
        2 | 2017-01-19 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   200 |   D
        3 | 2017-01-18 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   350 |   E
        3 | 2017-01-19 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   300 |   F
```

If you don't have too much foo, you might get away with it by filtering it on the client side, but most
of the time this is an anti pattern.

you can also make it with query:

```
select objectid, date, price, foo from report2 where report='latest' and price > 300 and price < 500 allow filtering;


 objectid | date                            | price | foo
----------+---------------------------------+-------+-----
        1 | 2017-01-19 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   400 |   B
        3 | 2017-01-18 23:00:00.000000+0000 |   350 |   E
```

Which is not ideal, but it kind of works.

The reason I'm creating partition latest is so that the partition remains on the same host. Depending
on the workload you get this might become a hot row for you.

This is more or less the relational side of the story ...

If you are truly working with cassandra you have to prepare the view up front. So you would have report 2
but would insert the data for every statistical group you want to get out i.e.

```
insert into report2 (report, objectid, date, price, foo) values ('300-500', 1, '2017-01-19', 300, 'A');
... and so on
```

and then you would do:

```
select objectid, date, price, foo from report2 where report='300-500'
```

But I guess you want to set the ranges dynamically so this is not what you want. This is more or less what basic cassandra does.

Then there are always materialized views (at the moment they have some issues) personally I wouldn't use them with some super important reports.

And if the access pattern is unknown, there is always apache spark or some scripting solution that check the data and creates views you need.

Comment: For table report2, can we use price in where clause? Because it is not clustering column and not indexed.

Comment: actually you can because if you scroll with the statement to the right I used `allow filtering;` I also explained possible approaches. There might be more approaches to this, but most of them don't really scale well. The problem of putting price into clustering column is that you get every unique price for foo ... and this is not what we want showed this in report table.

Comment: Svaljek I just added an answer, could you take a look at it.

Comment: nice idea, I think if you just drop the date it's what aseipel needs.
There is only one thing and I'm unable to check right now if the token function
would give you guarantee that if you have prices in between that it would include
the correct partitions. Using token function is when you just want to make sure
you get all the partitions when doing complete scans. I don't think they will be
there with ranges, please try with nums in between ... I just check online for
couple of murmur3 hashes ... and it doesn't look like they been sorted by price.

Comment: Cassandra I think when generating hashes uses first 64 bits, but the function is
128 bits so I just split it up here:

502b66896a0fe98b
05406e335b53c64a -> latest:100

1e181d53831bbf5b
dd5b33f75c79b21c  -> latest:200

873f0f288a18ca25
01187b4817ac9ee7  -> latest:300

5c6d490ab76a1f46
f64ae8c8486404e7 -> latest:400

Anyway ... please check if this works as expected :) I'm just not sure

Comment: I am not sure too, i will try later, as I learn cassandra out of my work time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I have just tried it out and it does seem to work. @MarkoŠvaljek would you mind briefly explaining how that solution works? I can't figure it out right now

Comment: Never mind, I think I got it - by setting (report, foo) as primary key, new inserts will overwrite older rows. However, this does not work if two different objects have the same value for foo - I would want both objects to be in the result set then. Sorry, I guess I didn't explain it accurately in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table report (
report text,
price int,
objectid int,
date timestamp,
foo text,
primary key ((report, price), foo)
);
```

you can run queries like --

```
select * from report where token (report,price) > token('latest',200) and  token (report,price) < token('latest',300);
```

This should give you price range between 200 and 300.

Modification after question changes --

```
create table product_history (
description  text,
createdOn bigint,
warehouse_location  text,
color text,
price int ,
primary key (description,createdOn, warehouse_location,price)
);
```

Use above table to keep the history.

Listing down your query -

```
1 -  Price of all objects with warehouse_location 23A from 2017-01-12 to 2017-01-18
```

Use this table -

```
create table product_by_latest_price (
description  text, -- I believe description of the product is not going to change, otherwise , use some UUID per product. 
createdOn bigint,
warehouse_location  text,
color text,
price int static,   -- this is shared value, per description.
primary key (description,createdOn, warehouse_location)
);
```

For this table, you dont have use update query, just keep inserting.    For example -

```
  insert into product_by_latest_price (description, createdOn, warehouse_location, color,price) values (Cucumber , '2017-01-12', 23A, 'green',100);
  insert into product_by_latest_price (description, createdOn, warehouse_location, color,price) values (Cucumber , '2017-01-18', 23A, 'green',200);
```

Select Query

```
select * from product_by_latest_price where warehouse_location = 23A and createdOn>= 2017-01-12 and 2017-01-12<=2017-01-18;  result would be row with price 200.
```

Color of all objects with price > 60 and price < 90 and date > 2017-01-11 and date < 2017-01-22

```
create table product_by_date_price (
description  text,
createdOn bigint,
warehouse_location  text,
color text,
price int ,
primary key (createdOn,price)
);

select * from product_by_date_price where token(createdOn)> token(2017-01-12) and  token(createdOn)<(2017-01-18) and price>60  and price < 80;
```

This will retun duplicate rows, you need to filter out at application level.

For insert use batch

```
BEGIN BATCH 

 insert into product_history .....
 insert into product_by_latest_price .....
 insert into product_by_date_price .....

END BATCh
```

I haven't tested any of the query, but this shoud work. Cassandra 3.0 has views, you can take advantage of views. Remeber, design you table according to your query. Do not hesitate to copy data.

Good luck.

Comment: Anyway this might work (unable to test right now) ... but generates a lot of partitions that might not be needed :) to be honest ... And the client would still need to sort by timestamp and then drop the others ... but very nice idea ... I'm sure I'll use this somewhere :p

Comment: Marko, By the way, how did you computed the hash?

Comment: @Gunwant did you try this out? It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: No, I did not try this. Ideally this should work by looking at datastax documentation. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Comment: With "SELECT * FROM report WHERE token(report, price) > token('latest', 300)" I get { objectid=1; date=2017-01-20; price=400; foo='B' } and { objectid=3; date=2017-01-18; price=400; foo='B' } (which would be wrong anyway, because object 3 has a more recent record that satisfies the condition). After adding "AND token(report, price) < token('latest', 500)" 0 rows are returned

Comment: Thats what i said, you have to filter again at application level, take the latest one.  Use comparator, compair based on foo and date.  but if you dont want to keep the history of change, we can design in other way.

Comment: How can I filter on application level if the query returns wrong or no results at all? Do you mean I should "SELECT *" without "WHERE"? That would not be an option, we're talking about more than 10^7 rows

Comment: Ideally we shoud keep two different tables, one for history and other to get the result for your query.

Comment: dont do select * . according to the results, you are getting values greater than 300, right. Only issue is, it returns previous older values as well, right ?

Comment: No, as stated above, if I select > 300 the query will return the wrong row for objectid 3, the right row is not in the result set

Comment: It is not wrong result according to u r query, it is returning greater than 300 value, what is wrong in that is the date which you have to filter ot in you java code. Or if you dont want to keep the history, we can redesign the table.

Comment: I guess I wasn't specific enough in my question, I was trying to come up with a simplification for a way more complex problem and I apparantly failed in doing so. My real data contains >10^7 rows and has dozens of "foo columns" (imagine price, weight, color, ...) which I want to filter arbitrarily (e.g. SELECT price, weight FROM report WHERE price > 500 AND color = "red" AND weight < 50). And, as I understand it from your answers, that would require a lot of different report tables if I wanted to use Cassandra

Comment: It is always helpful if you be specific in your question. The question u raised was very general , like how to get results less thsn 300 and greater than 200.

Comment: I calculated the hash by using online murmur3 hash generation form ... in the end it might not be 100% because I'm not sure if cassandra adds : between the keys or just takes them as they are (would have to look into the source) ... this is more or less assumption but looks like aseipel showed that the assumption was more or less correct.

Comment: I believe , using token() on partition keys would be more efficient than filtering a clustering column without using partition key.